# Are children listeners destroyed when the parent event ends?

Tags: javascript, event-listener

For example, if you have the code below, do the `mousemove` and `mouseup` events get destroyed when `mousedown` is not happening?

```
var el = document.getElementById('mydiv');
el.addEvenListener('mousedown', function(event){ 
  initializeStuff();

  document.onmousemove = function(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    showDragAnimation();
  };

  doucment.onmouseup = function() {
    showFinalPosition();
  };

}, false);
```

Comment: No, they are not, you've to remove them in the code.

Comment: No. Unless document is being destroyed, the events will work.

Comment: @Teemu OR @jsve, so that means `mouseup` will fire at any time?  Or will it fire only when `mousedown` is happening?

Comment: Umh... Actually `mouseup` can be fired only after `mousedown`, but `mousemove` will be fired despite of the mouse button being down or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they do not get destroyed - the `mousedown` is not known to be "not happening". Since JS doesn't run concurrently, that doesn't make sense anyway.

If your code did use `addEventListener`, it would be leaking event handlers horribly and your application would get very sluggy (more with every click). Only the fact that you're using old `on…` properties where you overwrite previous listeners saves you from that fate.

You will want to use

```
function onmousedown(event) {
    this.addEventListener("mousemove", onmousemove, false);
    this.addEventListener("mouseup", onmouseup, false);
    initializeStuff();
}
function onmousemove(event) {
    showDragAnimation();
}
function onmouseup(event) {
    this.removeEventListener("mousemove", onmousemove);
    this.removeEventListener("mouseup", onmouseup);
    showFinalPosition();
}

document.getElementById('mydiv').addEvenListener('mousedown', onmousedown, false);
```

Comment: Notice that sometimes `onmouseup` is not fired on the document when it happens outside the browser view. This can create odd experience, you might want to put some safeguards against that in place.

Comment: Thanks. I like your format better. Also,  regarding the adding the same EventListener to an element which you pointed out earlier: 
 
 *"If multiple identical EventListeners are registered on the same EventTarget with the same parameters, the duplicate instances are discarded. They do not cause the EventListener to be called twice, and since the duplicates are discarded, they do not need to be removed manually with the removeEventListener method."* 

[MDN source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Multiple_identical_event_listeners)

Comment: @ayjay: Yeah, but in your original code you have used function expressions which would lead to distinct functions indeed :-)